# Having trouble with CSS Faux Column layout--the background column image is not appearing

Tags: css

As stated, I'm trying to use the faux column approach to having matching-height columns. I've followed the approach listed in CSS: The Missing Manual, which matches everything I've seen on ALA and other online resources. The problem I'm having is that the faux column image never appears on the screen. Here is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
  <div id="reports">   
    <h2>yyyy</h2>  
    <p>xxxxx</p>                               
  </div>

  <div id="webApps">
    <h2>yyyy</h2>
    <p>xxxxx</p>
  </div>

  <div id="resources">
    <h2>yyyy</h2>
    <p>xxxx</p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <hr style="text-decoration:dotted" />
    <p> xxxx </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#contentWrapper {   
  background: url(fauxcolumn.png) repeat-y left top;
}
#reports {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#webApps {
  width: 150px;
  float:left;
  margin: 21px 100px 0px 80px;
}
#resources {
  width: 210px;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  margin-top: 21px;
}
#footer {
  clear:both;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: smaller;
  color: darkgray;
}
```

Comment: are you sure you have the correct link to the image? make sure the fauxcolumn.png is located in the same directory level as your page.

Comment: Yeah, I double--CRAP!

So yeah. I tried multiple times just to be SURE that the issue wasn't me mistyping the image, that the image itself had a problem, etc. Whenever I dragged a direct link to the image to the HTML it showed up fine. Same when I dragged the image into the CSS. I just forgot that the CSS was in a Styles subfolder and for the CSS I needed to go up a directory. I have no idea why it took me so long to put that together. 

Put that in an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulled from comment: Are you sure you have the correct link to the image? make sure the `fauxcolumn.png` is located in the same directory level as your page/stylesheet.

Comment: Putting the comment here so anybody else looking can see clearly what the problem was: 

I tried multiple times just to be SURE that the issue wasn't me mistyping the image, that the image itself had a problem, etc. Whenever I dragged a direct link to the image to the HTML it showed up fine. Same when I dragged the image into the CSS. I just forgot that the CSS was in a Styles subfolder and for the CSS I needed to go up a directory.